# Jquery mobile page doesnt show scrollbar

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im having a lot of trouble with the scroll of a my pages that i previous loaded into the dom, and after that,i transition to them, but when i do that my content div has for example 1500 px, but my page has only 547,a min-heigth=547 appears to, and i cant scroll my page.

this is my code:

loading:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load",
                "./pages/scoringCliente/selectScoringApps.html", {})
```

transition:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#selectScoringApps", {
        transition : "pop",
    });
```

html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="../../jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<link href="../../native/assets/www/default/css/jqueryMobileXXXXXXcss"
    rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="selectScoringApps_page" data-dom-cache="true">
        <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <img border="0" src="../../images/logo_header.png"
                    alt="Logo, Facebook" class="header_img headerDual_img" height="35" />
            </div>

            <h1 class="h1_header">
                Mobile<br>Scoring
            </h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            asdad <br> <br> <br> <br>
             <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>asd

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```